How to create only month range picker using syncfusion_flutter_datepicker
I am trying to do month range picker, but it is not working. I want to select the month range like date range and not to show date. User is not allowed to change the date. let say if user select Jan till March then
start date will be 01-01-2024
end date will  be 31-03-2024
here is my code.
 SfDateRangePicker(
              view: DateRangePickerView.month,
              selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
              onSelectionChanged: (DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {},
            ),

when i select any month calendar changes to dates. Please help how to do this, i've search alot on this, but no luck.
Expected output screenshot


@RandalSchwartz so you mean i should go for any other package instead of syncfusion_flutter_datepicker?

If you're committed to open source, yes.

You can use minDate and maxDate params for limiting the range. However, the user can still change view to years mannually by clicking on the year on top. This can be disabled by setting allowViewNavigation to false.
So in your case the complete code will look like this:
return SfDateRangePicker(
  minDate: DateTime(2024,1),
  maxDate: DateTime(2024,3,31),
  allowViewNavigation: false,
  view: DateRangePickerView.month,
  selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
  onSelectionChanged: (DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {},
)


but from your code i can't change the month. like when i tap on month, selection of month screen is not displaying because you did this  allowViewNavigation: false,. I want to pick the range of months. I have updated my question with expected output please check that

My bad, than you just have to change the view from view: DateRangePickerView.month to view: DateRangePickerView.year.
